# Выборка строк по дате с пропусками по часам

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день, есть таблица с данными, интервал записей разный от 1 минуты до нескольких дней
нужно выгрузить данные за весь период времени с интервалами 1 час (там где интервал больше нечего не поделать, но нужно как-то опустить те записи которые чаще чем 1 час)
Подскажите реально ли сделать запросом к субд или нужно формировать отдельную таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
ORDER BY
  created_at DESC;
```

Здесь `created_at` - поле типа `DATETIME`, при помощи функции `DATE_FORMAT()` отсекаем от времени минуты и секунды '2016-07-21 01' и группируем записи таблицы по полученной строке. MySQL возвращает одну запись из группы.

Comment: Или ошибку, если включен `sql_mode` `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. По-умолчанию в 5.7.

Comment: @Мелкий Режим SQL включают на уровне конфигурационного файла, он не включен в самом сервере по умолчанию. Включать sql_mode или нет в my.cnf решают разработчики дистрибутивов и пакетов (я напомню в документации еще и собирать самому MySQL не рекомендуют). Очень часто sql_mode в my.cnf нет в принципе (или есть, но не тот, который в документации), а если есть, разработчики почему-то стремятся его удалить из my.cnf для совместимости со всем остальным MySQL-сообществом и тогда остается голый сервер и в нем этот запрос работает, работает в том числе и в MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Уже включён. Если говорить точнее, то начиная с 5.7.5 `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` входит в значение по-умолчанию.

Comment: За все дистрибьютивы, конечно, не скажу - но официальные deb пакеты с repo.mysql.com - именно с активным `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. В `my.cnf` никакого `sql_mode` не указано. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-5.html  SQL Mode Notes Incompatible Change

Comment: Как раз получаю ошибку only_full_group_by, нашел варианты решения с ANY_VALUE(), но функция не корректно возвращает FLOAT поля, отключать ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY тоже не выход из положения

Comment: @user21736 Тогда что то типа `select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H') as created_at, min(field_1), max(filed_2), sum(field_3) from tbl group by DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H')` Идея в том, что надо принять для себя решение что делать с каждым из полей записи когда они задвоены и превращаются в одну - взять минимум, максимум или может быть сумму. Ни одного поля не включенного в group by без групповой функции в select оставаться не должно

Comment: разобрался, ANY_VALUE() возвращает FLOAT как DOUBLE, не знаю баг ли это но в принципе не критично. в общем в выборке нужно заместо * указать те поля которые нам нужны через функцию ANY_VALUE() - не агрегатная функция, как написано в документации создана для использования с only_full_group_by, если значения в выборке описаны с функцией ANY_VALUE() то флаг only_full_group_by будет игнорироваться сервером

Comment: @Мелкий у меня 5.7.11 - проверил на уровне самого сервера правило не включено, в my.cnf возможно, но по поводу my.cnf читай выше. Если у вас тысячи строк SQL-кода, вы скорее всего не будете его переписывать - это очень дорого и долго, особенно, в случае SQL. Вы просто отключите директиву в конфиге, вот если MySQL будет скомпилировано таким образом, что это правило будет по умолчанию, тогда да, нужно перерабатывать код (а лучше наверное и сразу менять СУБД).